# Sqlalchemy - return a collection of objects

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, relational-database, flask-sqlalchemy

I have following models:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    email = Column(String(120), unique=True)
    password = Column(String(12))
    balance = Column(Float())
    inventory = relationship("Inventory", primaryjoin="and_(User.id==Inventory.user_id, BaseGood.id==Inventory.basegood_id)", back_populates="user")


class Inventory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'inventory'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    basegood_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('basegoods.id'))
    producables_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('producables.id'))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    basegood = relationship('BaseGood', backref='basegoods', lazy="joined")
    user = relationship("User")

class Producable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'producables'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    price = Column(Float)
    time = Column(Integer)
    blueprint = relationship('BaseGood', secondary='blueprints', backref='producables', lazy="joined")

class BaseGood(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'basegoods'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    initprice = Column(Float)
    price = Column(Float)
    producable = relationship('Producable', secondary='blueprints', backref='basegoods', lazy="joined")
```

I understand that

`inventory = relationship("Inventory", backref='inventory', lazy='joined')`

should be the same. But I suspect I have to do some join here.

So when i now call `User.query.get(1).inventory` I get a collection of `Inventory` objects. On these i can then call `.basegood` or `.producable` respectively. That's not what I need.

What I want is a collection if `BaseGood` and `Producable` objects. I'd guess that magic needs to be applied here.

```
inventory = relationship("Inventory", primaryjoin="and_(User.id==Inventory.user_id, BaseGood.id==Inventory.basegood_id)", back_populates="user")
```

but i can't figure out the right join to make that happen.

Any hint is appreciated.
TIA

Comment: You can't have a mixed collection like that.

Comment: So do it with a method and return a list comprehension?